# How to install the IOP (Institute of Physics) Latex document class for Texlive and the Lyx Document Processor (Answer Provided)

Tags: latex, lyx

## Background

I originally asked a question on Stackoverflow, asking how I add the IOP document class to the list of available document classes in Lyx. (I will try to remove or merge that out dated quesiton.)

I now understand that this is a 2-stage process. Stage 1 is to install IOP styles and cls files etc for Texlive, and Stage 2 is to update Lyx to be able to use these.

I have now successfully done this on a Linux Mint distro. The method is described below. I will try to keep this updated if anything changes. Hopefully I have provided enough info for anyone to be able to do this regardless of distribution or OS. If not, add a comment so I can add required info.

## Useful References:

The following items helped me complete this process:

- Lyx Wiki Page for IOP: http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Iopart
- Section 5.1 of the Customization Manual (Help) Document provided in Lyx.

  Open Lyx and Goto: Help -> Customization -> Section 5.1 of Document
- The IOP Latex Document download page: ftp://ftp.iop.org/pub/journals/ioplatexguidelines.tar.gz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Stage 1 - Installing IOP Document Files for Texlive (Or Miktex)

*Windows Users: Check this link for directory location info:* http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Iopart

- The first step is to download the relevant files for IOP documents from here: ftp://ftp.iop.org/pub/journals/ioplatexguidelines.tar.gz

  If this link has expired, then do a duckduckgo search for "iop latex guidelines". The IOP have a .tar.gz file with all required files for Latex publishing included.

  - The next step is to find the correct Texlive directory. For me this was: `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex` If you are using miktex this will be different.
  - Using root privileges, create a directory in this folder: `sudo mkdir iopart`
  - Again using root privilages, extract the .tar.gz archive you downloaded to the directory `iopart`. After doing this and running the command `ls`, you should see the following files:

  `iopams.sty iopart12.clo IOPGraphicsGuidelines.pdf IOPLaTeXGuidelines.tex iopart10.clo iopart.cls IOPLaTeXGuidelines.pdf setstack.sty`

  Not all of these are important. You may wish to read through the PDF files which contain info on how to write an IOP accepted publication. I believe the `.tex` file contains an example template which may help you.

  - Finally, reconfigure Texlive by running the command `sudo texhash`.
  - You should now have the IOP Document Latex files installed and be able to use them with texlive.

## Stage 2 - Reconfigure Lyx

- This step is trivial, open Lyx and goto: [Menu Bar] -> Tools -> Reconfigure

## Stage 3 - Open a new Lyx Document and Test

- Goto: File -> New from Template -> Select `iop-article.lyx`
- Goto: Document -> Settings : Check that the document type is "iop article"
- Click the "View" button in Lyx which compiles and opens your document.
- You should see a example pdf file with some mock contents.

Comment: Current link seems to be https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/ioplatexguidelines.tar.gz